# Postgres is stuck when creating a database?

Tags: postgresql

I just installed Postgres on Ubuntu 20 on WSL. Both of the following are stuck forever:

```
CREATE DATABASE foo
WITH
OWNER = postgres      
ENCODING = 'UTF8'     
CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

And:

```
sudo -u postgres createdb foo
```

The log doesn't have anything:

```
postgres@postgres ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
postgres@postgres STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE foo
            WITH
            OWNER = postgres
            ENCODING = 'UTF8'
            CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

What are some possible causes for this?

Restarting Postgres or restarting the computer doesn't help and there's no locks. I also tried manually killing every lock.

Comment: Please share more details - is this even related to programming?

Comment: What kind of details? I installed Postgres, then the next step is creating a database, but it's hanging

Comment: If this is a pure problem with Postgres, it might be better suited at serverfault.com or dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @LeoJiang Have you found an answer? I'm also getting this behaviour in WSL1 with PostgreSQL 14 (13 works fine). I don't want to switch to WSL2.

Comment: I don't remember, probably just deleted the data directory and reinstalled

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with you. It seems that it has to do with the wsl version. I was running wsl 1 so I had to uninstall ubuntu 20.04 wsl, then set the verion to 2 with the following command

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

and then install ubuntu 20.04 wsl again. Now everything seems to be in order and I am able to create databases with no issues.

Comment: I had to use the command `wsl --set-default-version *distribution_name* 2` elsewhise it did not work on my computer. With the command `wsl -l -v` one can see which distribution is installed with which wsl version.

Comment: yes wsl 2 will not work for me see this error message.  C:\Users\rlc>wsl --set-version Ubuntu-22.04 2
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes.
The operation could not be started because a required feature is not installed.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateVm/HCS_E_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE     I have other virtual machines and wsl 2 is not possible. I need a wsl 1 solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is a work around:
Check you distros version by:

```
wsl -l -v
```

update the wsl version of you distros to 2 and then create the database it will get created.

Also other work arounds:

if you need to update the ubuntu switch back to wsl 1 and then update the ubuntu

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

after doing it switch back to wsl2

To update or degrade use the following commands:

Move to version 2:

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu-22.04 2
```

Back to version 1:

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu-22.04 1
```

Comment: I am not sure why your answer got downvoted. Actually one *can* change WSL version without destroying the whole distro, as you say. The conversion can take about 5 minutes but it's fine. It saves a lot of time that would be otherwise spend on installing & configuring everything again. So, thank you for this answer, it should get upvoted more.

Comment: @WojciechKaczmarek  this is the trick we can apply as a work around, Thanks for support.

Answer (score 2):

While the statement is hanging, connect to the `postgres` database and look in `pg_stat_activity` for the `wait_event` and `wait_event_type` of the hanging connection.

Very likely it is waiting for a lock. In that case, end the transaction that is holding the lock.

Answer (score 2):

take a look of

```
select * from pg_stat_activity sa inner join pg_locks l on sa.pid = l.pid
```

In my case I use wsl and get lock by AccessShareLock
its more a problem with wsl than postgresql

Comment: But how do you solve it? I seem to have the same issue as well

Comment: I stop using wsl!