# Creating SQL database takes infinite amount of time

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am on WSL (Ubuntu 22.04)

I've run
`sudo apt-get install postgresql`
`sudo -u postgres createuser -s user`
successfully

Yet when I try to run `createdb user` : the program seems stuck on an infinite loop, I have to interrupt it with Ctrl-C

When I try to run `CREATE DATABASE user OWNER user` after doing `sudo su postgres` and `psql` : same error

Answer (score 1):

It is more a problem with wsl than postgresql.

Solution:
Set the version to 2 with the following command

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

A similar problem already been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70836027/8727896)